# Limit of an element in a unital C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital C*-algebra. Show that an element $x$ of $A$ is self-adjoint if and only if $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{t}(||1+itx||-1)$=0.

My attempt: Suppose $x=x^*$. By functional calculus of x, there is the continuous function $f(\lambda)=1+it\lambda$ in $C(\sigma(x))$. Now $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{t}(||f||-1)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{t}(\sup_{\lambda\in\sigma(x)}|1+it\lambda|-1)$. Because of compactness of $\sigma(x)$, there is $\mu\in\sigma(x)$ such that $||f||=|f(\mu)|$, thus,$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{t}((1+t^2\mu^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}-1)=0$$
For converse direction, if $A$ is abelian, I can show it by using functional calculus of an arbitrary element and then easily I can conclude that this element is self adjoint. But now I can not use functional calculus, Please check my attempt and give me a hint for converse direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start by showing that the spectrum of $x$ is real. If it is not, then you can use $\sigma(1+itx)=1+it\sigma(x)$ and $\|1+itx\| \ge r_{\sigma}(1+itx)$.

Comment: @T.A.E.: I prove it in the following way:  suppose $\lim_{t\to 0}(\frac{1}{t})(||1+itx||-1)=0$ and $a+ib \in \sigma(x)$ , we have $$\frac{1}{t}(|1+it(a+ib)|-1)\leq \frac{1}{t}(||1+itx||_{sp}-1)\leq \frac{1}{t}(||1+itx||-1)$$
which shows that $\lim_{t\to 0}|\frac{1}{t}(|1+it(a+ib)|-1)|=0$, then 
$0=\lim_{t\to 0}|\frac{1}{t}((1-2tb+t^2b^2+t^2a^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}-1)|$ and using L'Hôpital's rule, we can conclude that $b=0$. So $\sigma(x)\subset {\Bbb R}$. Please check it.